# Vim text substitution - next n lines (not rest of file)

Tags: vim

I often want to squash git commits using vim (using rebase). I have a very nice shortcut for squashing all commits from the cursor to the end of file:

```
map s :,$s/^pick/squash/<CR>
```

But often don't want to apply this substitution to all remaining lines in the file, but to the next n lines. Is there a way to modify this command to only apply it to the next n lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know `n` beforehand (e.g, for 10):

```
nnoremap <buffer> s :,+10s/^pick/squash/<CR>
```

This changes the current line *and* the next 10 lines.

If you don't know `n` beforehand, you can try a visual mapping:

```
xnoremap <buffer> s :s/^pick/squash/<CR>
```

... so you first select your range (e.g. `V10j`) and then hit `s`.

Comment: This is the answer I want, though something's not quite right when I try to put this in `.vimrc`: `map s :s,+10/^pick/squash/<CR>` . I get `E486: Pattern not found: +10/^pick/squash/` Any ideas?

Comment: Got it: map `s :.,.+10s/^pick/squash/<CR>` http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Ranges . I'm not allowed to edit your answer since there are less than 6 chars changed. Could you update it before I mark it correct?

Comment: Done - I recommend using explicit `*noremap` forms whenever possible.

Comment: you can use `s` instead of `squash`, `:s/^pick/s/<CR>`

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can use some of the tools provided by Vim's [stock git ftplugins](https://github.com/tpope/vim-git) which provide the `:Squash`, `:Cycle`, ... commands. These are handy but a little lame on their own.

Put the following in `~/.vim/ftplugins/gitrebase.vim`:

```
nnoremap <buffer> S :Cycle<cr>:silent! call repeat#set('S')<cr>
xnoremap S :normal S<cr>:silent! call repeat#set(v:count1.'VS')<cr>'<
```

Now you can use `S` to cycle through the options. You can also visually select your lines and use `S`. As a bonus these mappings work with repeat.vim so that the `.` command still works

Comment: Nice answer! Voted. Perhaps the 2nd `silent` also wants a bang, to avoid showing an error if `vim-repeat` is not installed (if i remember correctly).